# css + selector in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I am new to SASS but enjoying it,

I am trying to figure out how I write this line of code in SASS:

```
 li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
   display: block; 
 }
```

I am very stuck, and could use some help.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to figure out how to do differently?  Isn't this working?

Comment: it's already written in SASS since SASS is CSS

Comment: You would just nest it like this `li { a { &:hover { + .hidden { your styles } } } }` I think four levels deep is about as many as you want to go in SASS.

Comment: This is close, and compiles as: li a:hover + .hidden, li a:hover .hidden:hover {
      display: block; }. it does not quite work though as I need the li a:hover to be missing

Comment: Nevermind, my last comment won't work either, just make two selectors. I think what you are trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense from a SCSS perspective, you're trying to apply a display block to two different selectors with different children and states. You could probably do a loop or something, but it's not worth it for this css rule in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in sass you must use the following structure:

```
li + .hidden
    a:hover .hidden:hover
        display: block
```

I hope help you. Good Luck

Comment: If I use that it then compiles as this: li + .hidden a:hover .hidden:hover {
  display: block; } and I need it to compile as:  li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
   display: block; 
 }

Comment: Oh ok. You just have to change the position of li + .hidden for .hidden + li